# Are runnable examples supported for pkgsite locally?

Tags: go, godoc, pkgsite

I have the following "whole file" example that works locally without issue:

```
func Example_should_be_runnable() {
    o := bytes.NewBufferString("")

    // RootCmd() just wraps &cobra.Command
    cmd := RootCmd()
    cmd.SetOut(o)
    cmd.SetArgs([]string{"--myarg=blah"})

    err := cmd.Execute()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(o)
    // Output:
  // expected_output
}
```

But when I spin up `pkgsite` locally and run the example on the webpage I see this error:

```
go: github.com/me/myproj@v0.0.0: reading https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/me/myproj/@v/v0.0.0.mod: 404 Not Found
    server response:
    not found: github.com/me/myproj@v0.0.0: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/177f425a899fd5149a7c1317bd8fa47cefb9929d4ba6abf74aad8c54d873f458: exit status 128:
        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
    Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
    If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

I'm trying to figure out whats happening, but I'm confused about what pkgsite is trying to do.

Is it trying to fetch my package from the public `https://proxy.golang.org` when running the example? Is that a bug/issue? Because the rest of my GoDoc document links (syntax like `[mypackage.PkgExamples]` for example) correctly go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` and work fine.

It shouldn't be going to `https://proxy.golang.org` at all when running locally right?

Comment: In order: yes, no, and no. GoDoc will serve the package you point it at from the local copy. No Go tool will *assume* that any package is available locally.

Comment: @Adrian is there support then for telling pkgsite to grab it locally from the filesystem? Is this a pkgsite thing or more specifically a playground thing? Maybe I need to configure playground to get it from the local filesystem?